# "@media all and (max-width: 945px)" not changing font-size at and below 945px

Tags: css

I've looked at several posts on the subject ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431939/the-min-max-width-media-query-doesnt-make-grammatical-sense)), and my reasoning should be solid:

```
@media all and (max-width: 945px) {
    div#browser-nav-nav-bar a, div#browser-nav-nav-bar p {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
}

div#browser-nav-nav-bar a, div#browser-nav-nav-bar p {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

However, the font size isn't changing. I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2hLow0c5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selectors are identical (so have equal specificity) so [the last font size defined will be the one that is applied](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order).

Move the `@media` block to the end of the stylesheet.

Comment: @somecbusnerd That's correct. The media query should be be after the main stylesheet or at the bottom of the style sheet after all the global styles.